# How to get button when clicked to go to a new website

Tags: html

Im creating a sample login page and i'm struggling to get the log in button to work. When the user inputs their data and selects from the drop down box they click the login button to get to the next page. The problem im having is when I click it dose nothing and just reloads the login page, how do I fix this.

```css
body{
    margin: auto;
    padding: auto;
    background: url(0001.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.logo{
    /* Commerce Bank Logo Picture */
    width: 250;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
}

.loginbox{
    /* Box */
    width: 620px;
    height: 520px;
    border-top: 10px solid #006548;
    background: white;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 70px 30px;
    opacity: 0.75;
}
.p{
    margin: 50px;
}
h3{
    /* Login Here Font */
    color: gray;
    font-size: x-large;
}
h1{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 22px;
}
.loginbox p{
    /* Username and Password  */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    
}

.loginbox input{
    /* Username and Password Input Look */
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.loginbox input[type="text"], input[type="password"]
{
    /* Input to the Enter Username and Enter Password */
    border: none;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: transparent;
    outline: none;
    height: 40px;
    color: #6E6F78;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.loginbox input[type="password"]:hover,input[type="text"]:hover,input[type="text"]:hover
{
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid lightblue;
}
.loginbox input[type="submit"]
{
    /* Blue Log in Button */
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    height: 80px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    background: #98C9DA;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-size: x-large;
}
.loginbox input[type="submit"]:hover
{
    cursor: pointer;
    background: lightblue;
    color: #fff;
}
.loginbox a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: darkgrey;
}

/* Drop Box  */
/* /************************** */
.container {
    width: 250px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
  }
  .select-container {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #fff;
    background: url("down-arrow-black-circular-button.svg");
    background-size: 20px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-y: 7.5px;
    background-position-x: 220px;
  }
  .select-container select {
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    background: transparent;
    font-size: 16px;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
       -moz-appearance: none;
            appearance: none;
  }
  .select-container:after {
    font-family: 'material icons';
    font-size: 24px;
    color: darkgrey;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    pointer-events: none;
  }
  .select-container:hover
{
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid lightblue;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Commerce Bank
</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<body>
    <div class="loginbox">
    <img src="logo.png" class="logo">
        <h3>Log in to Account Here</h1>
        <form>
            <p>Username:</p>
            <input type="text" name="" placeholder="">
            <p>Password:</p>
            <input type="password" name="" placeholder="">
            <p>Login As:</p>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="select-container">
                  <select>
                    <option value="">Admin</option>
                    <option value="">User</option>
                  </select>    
                </div>
              </div>
            <input type="submit" name="" value="Log in" onclick="location.href='http:www.example.com'">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  You have an onClick handler that reloads the page just as you programmed it.  If you instead use the form action attribute, you can handle the form as you like.

Comment: Please [learn to love labels](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/)

Answer (score 2):

The JavaScript `location.href=...` causes the browser to make a GET request to the specified URL and navigate to it.

Submitting a form causes the browser to make a GET (the default) or POST request (as specified by the `method` attribute of the `<form>`) to the URL specified in the `action` attribute (defaulting to the current URL if there isn't an `action` attribute) with the data from the form in it.

---

It does not make sense to put `location.href=...` on a submit button as you can't navigate to two URLs at the same time. (If we leave new windows and frames out of the discussion).

Pick one.

Either you just want to:

- link to a URL (in which case don't use a form, and don't use JavaScript for that matter, just use a `<a href="...">regular link</a>`
- submit the form data somewhere (in which case specify the `action` of the form and get rid of the JS).

Answer (score 1):

just give the form action the href directly

```css
body{
    margin: auto;
    padding: auto;
   // background: url(0001.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.logo{
    /* Commerce Bank Logo Picture */
    width: 250;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
}

.loginbox{
    /* Box */
    width: 620px;
    height: 520px;
    border-top: 10px solid #006548;
    background: white;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 70px 30px;
    opacity: 0.75;
}
.p{
    margin: 50px;
}
h3{
    /* Login Here Font */
    color: gray;
    font-size: x-large;
}
h1{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 22px;
}
.loginbox p{
    /* Username and Password  */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    
}

.loginbox input{
    /* Username and Password Input Look */
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.loginbox input[type="text"], input[type="password"]
{
    /* Input to the Enter Username and Enter Password */
    border: none;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: transparent;
    outline: none;
    height: 40px;
    color: #6E6F78;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.loginbox input[type="password"]:hover,input[type="text"]:hover,input[type="text"]:hover
{
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid lightblue;
}
.loginbox input[type="submit"]
{
    /* Blue Log in Button */
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    height: 80px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    background: #98C9DA;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-size: x-large;
}
.loginbox input[type="submit"]:hover
{
    cursor: pointer;
    background: lightblue;
    color: #fff;
}
.loginbox a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: darkgrey;
}

/* Drop Box  */
/* /************************** */
.container {
    width: 250px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
  }
  .select-container {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #fff;
   // background: url("down-arrow-black-circular-button.svg");
    background-size: 20px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
   // background-position-y: 7.5px;
  //  background-position-x: 220px;
  }
  .select-container select {
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    background: transparent;
    font-size: 16px;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
       -moz-appearance: none;
            appearance: none;
  }
  .select-container:after {
  //  font-family: 'material icons';
    font-size: 24px;
    color: darkgrey;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    pointer-events: none;
  }
  .select-container:hover
{
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid lightblue;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Commerce Bank
</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<body>
    <div class="loginbox">
    <img src="logo.png" class="logo">
        <h3>Log in to Account Here</h1>
        <form action= "https://stackoverflow.com/"  >
            <p>Username:</p>
            <input type="text" name="" placeholder="">
            <p>Password:</p>
            <input type="password" name="" placeholder="">
            <p>Login As:</p>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="select-container">
                  <select>
                    <option value="">Admin</option>
                    <option value="">User</option>
                  </select>    
                </div>
              </div>
            <input type="submit" name="" value="Log in" >
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```